# Variable inside a square bracket in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

What does it mean to have a variable inside square brackets? Boolean?

For example:

1. `[ $FILES ] || { print "File not found." }`
2. `[ $VERIFY ] && { print "file verification fail" }`

Comment: It is *testing* whether `FILES` and `VERIFY` are set. `[ ... ]` is equivalent to `test` in bash. If the variables are *unset*, then `[ $varname ]` will test false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` invokes the `test` command which allows you to run conditional tests based on what arguments you supply inside them.

For the examples you have supplied:

- `$FILES` is a single argument, so the test will return True if the argument is not null. Piped with `||` (Logical OR), whenever $FILES is 'null', `test` will return a non-zero exit status (1) thus printing "File not found."
- Ditto for `$VERIFY` except being piped with `&&` means that `print "file verification"` will execute as long as $VERIFY is not null (as `test` will return a status of 0 in this case).

I will also add that there also exists `[[]]` which is the 'newer' test and is more commonly used

EDIT: I would also recommend enclosing variable names in double quotes ("") as they are technically arguments to a command.